# Getting SSL to work on Django project

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, iptables, ssl, django

I'm trying to get my Django website to move entirely to `https` (currently it's solely `http`). The webserver is nginx (reverse proxy) and gunicorn.

However, even after correctly installing SSL, opening port 443 and tweaking my nginx virtual host file, I'm unable to connect to my website over `https://example.com` (`http://example.com` works fine). Can someone guide me regarding how to troubleshoot this?

Here are the details:

In `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` (I use the `iptables-persistent` package), I have this snippet among other lines:

```
# Acceptable TCP traffic
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

If I write `sudo netstat -4plunt`, the output shows me port 443 is listening:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18445/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      923/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      719/postgres    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18445/nginx
```

My nginx virtual host file in the `sites-enabled` folder houses the following code:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myserver.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    charset utf-8;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {

        root /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {

        root /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/;
    }

    location /status {
        stub_status on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 40.114.247.165;
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffers 8 24k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        include proxy_params;
        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;
        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_whitelist.rules;
        proxy_pass          http://unix:/home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/myproject.sock;

    }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/templates/;
   }
}
```

Lastly, I added the following line to my django project's `settings.py` file:

`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`

After having done all of the above changes, I still can't get to run my website on `https`; the connection always times out.

Can someone assist me with where to begin troubleshooting this problem? Ask me for more information in case you needed it.

---

Complete rule set in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` is as follows:

```
*filter
# Allow all outgoing, but drop incoming and forwarding packets by default
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Custom per-protocol chains
:UDP - [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:ICMP - [0:0]

# Acceptable UDP traffic

# Acceptable TCP traffic
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Acceptable ICMP traffic

# Boilerplate acceptance policy
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop invalid packets
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Pass traffic to protocol-specific chains
## Only allow new connections (established and related should already be handled)
## For TCP, additionally only allow new SYN packets since that is the only valid
## method for establishing a new TCP connection
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP

# Reject anything that's fallen through to this point
## Try to be protocol-specific w/ rejection message
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# Commit the changes
COMMIT

*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

`/proc/net/ip_tables_matches` contains:

```
conntrack
conntrack
conntrack
udplite
udp
tcp
icmp
```

`proxy_params` included in my nginx virtual host file contain the following:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection may be timed out because your Iptables may be not correct at some point.

Try to flush your Iptables (save them first if you have some work in there)
These would be good to add after the flush test.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# Allow inbound traffic from established connections.
# This includes ICMP error returns.
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: the listen state is just fine, try to execute lsof -i :443 and you will find who is behind, but either try my advice or provide the full iptables listing

Comment: what iptables modules you have loaded cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches, also please note that root directive should be in server block and not in location blocks... https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: Moreover, my DB is hosted separately on another machine. So far I've assumed that I don't have to open port 443 on that separate machine. That can't be the problem right?

Comment: ok, the /proc/net/iptables shows you have the conntrack and other modules you are using from iptables, so I asked this just to make sure these are available on the system

Comment: "my DB is hosted separately on"... is this Google machine, I know at one time Google offered free databases for Django projects. If this is the case they opened the port 443 for sure, if not can you check if you have open connection to that port from that machine.

Comment: Well on my DB, port 80 isn't listening either, but my web application is working, so that's probably not needed. It's set up on Azure btw, it's not one of those Google offerings.

Comment: Just noticed you are using the socket via http : http://unix:/home/myuser/myprojectfolder/myproject/myproject.sock; try https:// also you can isolate if iptables are problem by stopping them. For instance on centos I would write service iptables stop, or service iptables start, and services iptables status for status

Comment: Same commands for Ubuntu as well - will try that. **Good catch** on my unix socket. Though if i make that https, I wouldn't be able to accept http traffic at all. I do want to accept both http and https at first (and them have a redirect later for http to https). So if you have any suggestion for that, please do let me know.

Comment: the last one would be easy with 2 server blocks:
`server {
  listen 80;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 443;
  ...
}` inside the same file but you will differentiate the socket protocol.

Comment: Hmm okay. Going to test it, and mark this answer correct if everything works. Do include the bit about changing http to https in the unix socket in your answer as well.

Comment: if it works I will update it, no worries.

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't enough to work. Maybe it's the `proxy_params` I add in the `location` block via `include proxy_params;`? I've added those variables at the end of my question as well, have a look.

Comment: try proactive in there, and let me know if you were able to fix this problem. I thought this is iptables problem at first, but I cannot dig deeper right now, sorry.

Comment: Well the latest thing I'm about to try is binding to an `http` socket instead of a unix socket (in gunicorn), and seeing if nginx can get a response from that.

Comment: please also check this story: https://gist.github.com/davewongillies/6897161

Comment: Finally got it to work. Your answer helped, but my ports were also a problem. Thanks prosti!